# Stretching div but not all over the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a frame with dynamic height.
In it, I have 3 sections, one of them is the content section.

I want to pin the content's edges to a constant distant from the frame.

Here is [a fiddle to reproduce the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/BV5Z6/2/). I am using the jquery-ui-dialog in the fiddle just because it is easier use when reproducing the problem. The solution cannot involve jquery-ui-dialog specific code. it can use jquery and jquery-ui though.

A CSS solution if exists is preferable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the "**alsoResize**" option... then , your content will grow at the same time as the container.

Quote:

```
Resize these elements synchronous when resizing.

Code examples

Initialize a resizable with the alsoResize option specified.
$( ".selector" ).resizable({ alsoResize: ".other" });
Get or set the alsoResize option, after init.
//getter
var alsoResize = $( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "alsoResize" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "alsoResize", ".other" );
```

Source: [jQuery UI - Resizable option-alsoResize](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-alsoResize)

Comment: You rock! I wish I had a CSS solution, but I doubt if one exists. 
I created a fiddle with your solutions for those who are interested. http://jsfiddle.net/F4XgM/

Comment: I'm glad it works, and yeap, you could do it with css (based on well commented by @Sotiris plus a few mod.), but since you use jQ+UI, with this you only need to add one line to the code... as we can see in your example ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Positioning the elements is easier to solve issues such the one you describe. For example you can use `position:absoulte`. Then using `top`,`right`,`bottom` & `left` properties you can position the element where is required. Here a sample css:

```
#content {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    bottom: 34px;
    top: 34px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    position: absolute;
}
#footer {
    border: 1px solid green;
    bottom: 10px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BV5Z6/4/

Comment: This is a really good answer, but it still assumes the title is only one line.. is there something resolve it regardless to title height? http://jsfiddle.net/5ZnjH/

Comment: @guymograbi you could use jquery to set dynamicly the value of `top` property for `#content`. For example: `$("#content").css('top',$('#title').height()+12);` Of course using this method you have to set a default height for you dialog.